# Adjusting bike fitting to cope with FAI (hip deformity)

Tags: bike-fit, health, pain, injury, adaptive

After many years in the saddle (as a casual rider only) I am currently unable to ride to due a problem with my hips. I just got the X-rays back and it seems I have a ["pincer" deformity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femoroacetabular_impingement) on both hips which is causing pain and limited motion. I am hoping this can be treated with pain meds and possibly surgery in the near future, and then I'll obviously be wanting to start riding again. To avoid a recurrence of this problem it seems I may have to pay more attention to the fit of my bike, and how I sit. From what I've read so far it seems that my cranks may be a little too long for my leg length, and perhaps a more upright riding position will also help to reduce the effect of hip joint impingement. Has anyone else had to deal with anything similar, or have any suggestions as to how to reduce the impact on hip joints ?

Comment: It's possible in some places to have a bike fit from a physiotherapist. Not cheap, and they usually work with teams, but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks - good idea - will probably need some physio as part of any treatment in the coming weeks, so will look into the possibility of combining that with bike fitting - with any luck the insurance may cover it.

Comment: Any problems with foot direction? I have duck feet, so had to get custom speedplay with different length spindles to accommodate heels that point in. That might also be something to look at.

Comment: @JohnP: actually, yes, same problem - this may even have been the root cause of the hip deformities. I guess we need to ensure that our feet point outwards on the pedals. I read somewhere also that positioning the feet further apart can help with hip impingement

Comment: Yeah, it was $$ to get them custom (abt 300 IIRC), but well worth it. Also improved my power output by ~ 10-15 watts on average.